# Backbone context issue with coffeescript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a simple calendar that re-renders whenever the date changes. After `onClick` the date is set triggering the change:date event and the render method is called.

However, the context is off as the html is not being replaced.

I don't know why this is so because I am using `=>` to preserve the context and when I `console.log @$el` it always shows me the same class ie. WidgetView

It works when I do `$(elementName).html` but not with `@$el.html`. Ideas?

```
class WidgetView extends sandbox.mvc.View

  className: 'sidebar-group'

  events:
    "click a" : "onClick"

  template: sandbox.template.compile tmpl

  initialize: (options) ->
    @date = new DateModel {rid:1000}
    @listenTo @date, "change:date", @render

  onClick: (e) ->
    e.preventDefault()
    # Get value
    value = $(e.currentTarget).text()
    # Set date model
    @date.set {date:value}
    # Emit model change event
    sandbox.emit "model.date.change", @date
    return false

  render: (model) =>
    data = CalendarResource()
    @$el.html @template {calendar: data}
    @
```

Comment: You don't need to use the fat arrow when defining instance methods. That *might* be the problem...

Comment: I've tried it both ways. Funny enough, if I set the @date from ANOTHER class instance, the view re-renders correctly

Comment: here is the gist - https://gist.github.com/imrane/5725525

Comment: I think it has something to do with the datasource.coffee...maybe not cloning properties properly?

Comment: figured it out - im using the pageslide plugin which was copying over the html into another DIV...all the nodes look the same but you aren't seeing the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The issue for this particular problem was that I was using the JQuery Page Slide plugin which was copying over the element to another node.

As a result, I was updating the reference node and the plugin was not keeping the new node in sync.

### Solution

Since there was no refresh method for the plugin, I will have to copy over the elements and rebind all events.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is pretty simple. Look at listenTo closely if you didn't read it.

> object.listenTo(other, event, callback)

Unlike bind

> object.on(event, callback, [context])

If you see listenTo doesn't set the context of your callback in any shape or form.

Try just doing

```
  @listenTo @date, "change:date", _.bind(@render, this);
```

Bleh I'm not a coffee scripter but you get the point. Force the context in the constructor to always be the instance.

Comment: Thanks but the issue was in fact that I was using the pageslide plugin which copied the elements into another div...so what I was seeing on the screen wasn't the backbone.view